# How to improve a join between two Json results?

Tags: java, list, join, jackson

I am attempting to merge two API results which both return JSON into a single list of objects.

Currently, I'm basically iterating through two for loops, to match up the entries in each list.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?  The process is currently taking much too long for my liking.

I have the following code:

```
private List<SingularEntry> combineAdsAndCreatives(JsonNode creativeEntries, JsonNode adEntries) 
{
     List<SingularEntry> entries = new ArrayList<SingularEntry>();
     for (JsonNode node : adEntries) {
          node = adHashToNode(node, creativeEntries);
          if(node != null)
          {
               entries.add(convertNode(node));
           }
     }
     return entries;  
}

private JsonNode adHashToNode(JsonNode node, JsonNode creativeEntries) 
{
   for(JsonNode creativeNode : creativeEntries)
   {
        if( node.get("campaign_network_id").toString().equals(creativeNode.get("campaign_network_id").toString())    &&                   node.get("ad_network").toString().equals(creativeNode.get("ad_network").toString()) )
         {
           ObjectNode newNode = (ObjectNode) node;
           newNode.put("image_hash", creativeNode.get("image_hash"));
           newNode.put("creative_name", creativeNode.get("creative_name"));
           return newNode;
         }
       }
       return null;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to define a JsonNodeWrapper class which keeps the JsonNode and define equals() method (also you may need hashCode() method) to compare the wrapper with another JsonNode wrapper.

The go through both lists creating the JsonNodeWrappers and place all the created ones into a Set to leave unique ones only.

Comment: Whats the difference? It would still be looping though both lists twice, no?

Comment: No, loop once for each list. Your posted code loops N*M. For each eleemnt in the first list it does loop through the second list

Comment: Can you show what you mean by "go through both lists then"?

Comment: for(JsonNode node : creativeEntries) { setInstance.add(new JsonNodeWrapper(node) } and the same for the second list

Comment: Sorry I must be slow. I'm not seeing how that will allow me to add the image hash from one list into the node object of the other list :(

Comment: So the requirement is to init image_hash right? Place the first list in the set. Go through the second list and for each element check whether it exists in the set. If exists copy the image_hash. If not jjust add the node wrapper to the set

Comment: I've edited your answer with what I believe you were telling me to do. Please correct it if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I would say it's not correct creativeEntries.contains(node) in fact is the same loop hidden in one method

Comment: I'm really lost then. How do I see if it exists?

Comment: By checking existence in Set where all the entries of the first list were added